# Migration targets 2.1.0-rtm-30799 even though Target Framework is .Net Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am using VS2017 version 15.7.3

I am curious as to why a new solution will create a database with migrations listed as being version 2.1.0 but if the identity tables for the very same database are added via the PM Console then the migration will be listed as rtm.

Steps to demonstrate what I mean.

I build a new solution using the ASP.NET Core Web Application template
[image: web application template]

Choosing Individual User Accounts for Authentication
[image: as shown here]

Then the generated code shows that the data migration will have ProductVersion 2.1.0

```
namespace WebApplication14.Data.Migrations
{
    [DbContext(typeof(ApplicationDbContext))]
    partial class ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
    {
        protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
            modelBuilder
                .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "2.1.0")
                //etc
```

I run the application, register a user and click Migrations Applied to create the database.

[image: creating the database]

Next

1. I use SQL Server Object Explorer to delete all the tables.
2. I delete the Migrations folder from the solution
3. In Package Manager Console I type

   Add-migration one

Now the ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot refers to the rtm ProductVersion

```
namespace WebApplication14.Migrations
{
    [DbContext(typeof(ApplicationDbContext))]
    partial class ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
    {
        protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
            modelBuilder
                .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "2.1.0-rtm-30799")
```

If I then run

update-database

the tables get created in the database with the rtm product version listed in __EFMigrationsHistory

I am wondering if this difference is by design or not and if so why it is designed that way.

Comment: update VS to latest version

Comment: @viveknuna done, but no change